# Passing variables into a CMS block

Tags: magento-1, cms, cms-block, template-directive

I have a cms block that is added to a page via layout xml.

```
<block type="cms/block" name="my_cms_block" as="my_cms_block">
    <action method="setBlockId">
        <block_id>my_cms_block</block_id>
    </action>
</block>
```

It is then used on a page with the following snippet.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_cms_block'); ?>
```

Now what I would like to do is be able to pass variables into this block from the page that can be used in the cms block itself via `{{var something}}`

For example we have a cms block that we want to use across a selection of product pages but in this block we want to be able to use a product attribute say name or anything really.

Comment: Can you give a real example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Marius I added our example

Comment: Perhaps? https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_ExtendedFilter

Comment: @B00MER thanks I will take a look into this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a solution for passing variables to the block, but I have an other solution involving  custom `{{...}}` directives.

Here is a way to achieve what you need in your real scenario.

You need to put this in the block content

```
{{attribute attribute="name"}}
```

change `name` to what ever attribute code you need.

Now you need to create the `attribute` directive.  You can basically use anything as the directive name, but make sure it is one work without any uppercase letters. So `{{attr}}` is ok `{{productAttr}}` does not work.

The cms blocks are parsed using the `Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter`, so you need to rewrite that class and add a new method:

```
public function attributeDirective($construction) //handles {{attribute ....}}
{
    if (!isset($construction[2])) { //if no parameters are passed ({{attribute}}) do nothing
        return '';
    }
    if (!Mage::registry('current_product')) { //if not on product context
        return '';
    }
    $params = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]);
    if (!isset($params['attribute'])) { //if no attribute code is passed
        return '';
    }
    $attributeCode = $params['attribute']; //get the attribute code
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product'); //get the current product
    $value = $product->getData($attributeCode); //get the value of the attribute
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Helper_Output $helper */
    $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output'); //get the output helper. The attribute might allow HTML so that needs to be parsed also.
    return $helper->productAttribute($product, $value, $attributeCode); //return the processed attribute value
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know the flow of these Directive functions? when do they get called and maybe also why adding a new one just works by magic. I am lazy and cannot be bothered to xdebug it myself

Comment: @DavidManners When calling the `filter` method on the block content, you end up in `Varien_Filter_Template::filter`. This method handles first the directives `{{if..}}` and `{{depend..}}`. Apparently these are important (don't know why). Then it magically maps every {{something...}} directive to the method [`somethingDirective`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php#L158). If the method exists, and passes to it the params you pass to the directive `{{something p1=v1 p2=v2}}`. The response of the method replaces the directive in the template.